# Laravel validator check existence for multiple fields

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-validation

I'm creating a user login form where user can use his/her username or email to login with Laravel, so on the backend, I want to validate if the user input is either an existed username or an existed email address, something like

```
    $validator = Validator::make(
        array('username_or_email' => $username_or_email),
        array('username_or_email' => 'exists:users,username|exists:users,email)
    );
```

but I doubt the above is the correct syntax for it, so how should I write my validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't allow `@` in username you could do it this way:

```
if (strpos($username_or_email, '@') === false) {
   $rule = 'exists:users,username';
}
else {
   $rule = 'exists:users,email;
}


$validator = Validator::make(
        array('username_or_email' => $username_or_email),
        array('username_or_email' => $rule)
    );
```

Comment: Didn't know I could customize validator rules, thanks!